# How can I avoid using too many classes in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap css framework. I want to create a table which has many styles. The code is like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
  ....
</table>
```

How can I avoid using so many classes (table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed) here?
Can CSS do something like OO extend? I mean define a class named myTable and it can have many predefined styles.

Dummy code:

```
table.myTable{
  have_class: table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed;
}
```

Comment: Consider LESS http://lesscss.org/ (requires javascript). Take a look at `Mixins`, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: @kaveman: Twitter Bootstrap already uses LESS anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. Generally you want to use classes only when you have to, and then target by element first. If it's not possible by `.class element` then add another class. Remember, you can target more specifically by putting a space and adding another class/ID/element. The more you add, the more specific it becomes.

examples

`table`

`#myTable tr`

`#myTable tr.first`

`#myTable .odd a`

Also, if this is a problem with pre-defined twitter bootstrap classes, that is the problem with using a grid/styled boilerplate. It's not lightweight or lean by any stretch of the imagination. Twitter bootstrap is generally just for getting things up quickly, and prototyping... not for completed websites.

If youre looking for completely clean code, you'd want to code it from scratch.

Comment: I mean I just want to make my code clean. Something like inheritance in OOP. For example I have classA and classB, both of them have 2 attributes, then I have a classC extending the classA and classB. The classC should have 4 attrbiutes from classA and classB. Can this thing happen in CSS?

Comment: note that it will not make your generated code any cleaner. The output is still the same. It only makes writing the code easier.